# How to solve "error:linker command failed with exit code 1" in Flutter Xcode build?

Tags: ios, flutter, push-notification

In my **flutter project**, I made necessary changes to integrate one-signal push notification. For that, I followed the given documentation exactly the way it was described-

https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/flutter-sdk-setup

I have set the deployment target to `iOS 13.2`

The **enable bitcode option for my project** has been set to NO and the **enable bitcode option** for OneSignalNotificationExtension has been set to YES.

I copied the following code in my `Podfile` just before post_install-

```
target 'OneSignalNotificationServiceExtension' do   pod 'OneSignal', '>= 2.9.3', '< 3.0' end
```

Then, I reopened the my Workspace and after running clean build it is showing the following error-

> Xcode's output: ↳
>       === BUILD TARGET Pods-Runner OF PROJECT Pods WITH CONFIGURATION Release ===
>       ld: '/Users/project_directory/build/ios/Release-iphoneos/FMDB/libFMDB.a(FMDatabase.o)'
>   does not contain bitcode. You must rebuild it with bitcode enabled
>   (Xcode setting ENABLE_BITCODE), obtain an
>       updated library from the vendor, or disable bitcode for this target. file
>   '/Users/project_directory/build/ios/Release-iphoneos/FMDB/libFMDB.a'
>   for architecture arm64
>       clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

**So, I need a solution of this issue to run push notification in my ios device.**

Answer (score 0):

Set `Enable Bitcode` to `NO` in both targets. I mean for your app target and for the notification service extension target. And set your deployment target for your notification service extension to `10.0` as it is recommended in the [documention](https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/flutter-sdk-setup) and it'll not affect your app's deployment target. Then install pod again and check!